# How to pass a file from a Windows VM to a linux VM

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vagrant

I set up 2 machines, one Windows Server and an Ubuntu 20.04, both with an internal network.
They can ping each other correctly and have internet access. I'm trying to send a file from the Windows machine to the Linux machine without going through the host. Is this possible?

I'm using vagrant and virtualbox to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do yhis.  All you need to do is find a compatible protocol.

The way I would do it is via the ssh protocol - simply ensure SSH is set up on the Linux box and use winscp or equivalent to transfer files.

Others have mentioned setting up an http server, ftp and SAMBA.

Another unmentioned protocol is nfs (although samba is likely easier)

Answer (score 1):

You could use FTP for that.

Install an FTP server in Ubuntu and use the FTP client in Windows Server
to copy the file.

Reference for Ubuntu :
[How To Install an FTP Server On Ubuntu with vsftpd](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-vsftpd).

For Windows Server, setting up an FTP client depends on the Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

I am using VMware so may be a bit different.  Easier to map from Linux to Windows.

Mapping the other way requires installing and implementing Samba on the Linux machine.

On the Linux machine, Linux File Explorer:

SMB://Windows_name_or_IP/shared_folder .

Once the drive is mapped, you can move files in either direction.

Make sure Network Discovery and File/Print sharing are enabled on the Windows machine.

Connect and Authenticate.

That works here just fine, Kali and Ubuntu.

So the answer to your question is Yes, you should be able to connect the two systems without going through the host.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I'm trying to send files between to computers and I'm just really lazy, I just use python3's integrated HTTP server, not sure if that's a thing on Windows though.

```bsh
cd /into/directory/with/file
python3 -m http.server
```

then, on the receiving computer, just open [ip-address]:8000 and download the file.